# header hide for a particular page in my angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I m working on angular project and my need is hide header block on login page only. I tried to hide header on login page. But it still doesn't work for me. Can you any one help me to hide it on login state.

Here my index html

```
<div ng-include src="'views/header.html'"  ng-hide="$state.current.name === 'login'"></div>

    <div class="">
      <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
```

Here my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('Qapp', ["ui.router", "ngRoute"])

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    //$urlRouterProvider.when('/dam', '/dam/overview');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    $stateProvider
      .state('base', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'views/base.html'
      })
        .state('login', {
          url: '/login',
          parent: 'base',
          templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
          controller: 'LogCt'
        })
        .state('dam', {
          url: '/dam',
          parent: 'base',
          templateUrl: 'views/dam.html',
          controller: 'DamCt'
        })


  });
```

Comment: Tip: I would use "ng-if" instead of "ng-hide" and for better readability create a function in your mainCtrl like "ShowHeader()" and you can't directly access $state in the View you need a Controller where you can Inject the $state Provider and there you can access the $state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have access to `$state` object directly on HTML. For get access to it you should put `$state` object with the `$scope`/`$rootScope`, You could do this in `run` block/`controller` & use `$state.includes` instead of `$state.current.name`

**Markup**

```
<div ng-include src="'views/header.html'"  ng-hide="$state.includes('login')">
</div>
```

**Code**

```
app.run(function($state, $rootScope){
   $rootScope.$state = $state;
})
```

Comment: @BhavanKumarNatarajan Glad to help you, Thanks ;)