# Based on selected page show/hide header badge in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using Metronic AngularJS theme ([click here](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_1_angularjs/#/dashboard.html)) and developing an application using AngularJS and MVC. The sidebar, header and footer is divided into different sections. We are just including them using the below code.

```
<div data-ng-include="'~/App/common/views/layout/header.cshtml'" data-ng-controller="common.views.layout.header as vm" class="page-header navbar navbar-fixed-top md-shadow-zero-light">
```

In the header we have one badge, which we want to show for other pages not for the dashboard. When user open the dashboard then it should hide and for others it should show. 
I am trying to resolve this issue using the flag, this flag is defined under header controller.

My problem is that when we navigate between pages then it is not calling the header controller again. it is calling and loading once.

Can any body help me, how I can resolve this issue?

**Resolved Problem:**

I resolved my problem by using the below code.

```
<li data-ng-show="$state.includes('incentives')" class="dropdown dropdown-quick-sidebar-toggler">

app.run(function($state, $rootScope){
```

$rootScope.$state = $state;
});

I resolved my problem with the help of [Pankaj Parker's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2435473/pankaj-parkar) [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493023/header-hide-for-a-particular-page-in-my-angular).

Comment: show your code with flag that you used

Comment: Here is a screenshot.
http://screencast.com/t/h3V97KFf9cd

I think this is not a right way to use this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are better ways to achieve what you want, but that would probably involve a significant refactory in your code which might not be what you want. To get what we have now to work, I'd suggest using a ternary in `data-ng-include` which, remember, accepts an expression.

If possible, try this:

```
<div data-ng-include="vm.currentLocation === true ? '~/App/common/views/layout/header.cshtml' : null" ...rest of the line
```